# Put check box listener into button listener

Tags: java, android, button, checkbox, onclicklistener

I have a save `button` and `checkbox` in **Activtiy A**.

When save `button` is clicked, it will display the `checkbox` text if `checkbox` is **checked**.

```
         save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // if save button clicked

                         @Override
                         public void onClick(View v) {
                                 if(checkbox.isChecked()) {
                                     returnIntent.putExtra("outstation", checkbox.getText().toString());
                                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),checkbox.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                 }
                              }
                          });

     public void addListenerOnChk() // for checkbox
        {
            checkbox=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

            checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                        if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked())
                        {
                              // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),checkbox.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }

                });
            }
```

The above code works fine but it looked weird. I define `addListenerOnChk()` in `OnCreate` method. How can I put the check box inside save `onClick` instead of create two seperate `OnClick` ? (One is save button and another is checkbox)

Comment: ""  When save button is clicked, it will display the checkbox text if checkbox is checked. ""

then why you have written this statement?

if you want to perform check listener then you should write that. same is valid for all the views

Comment: @gvsharma Does the code look correct? Must have two onClick ?

Comment: actually you don't required to write onclick or check listener for checkBox.

remove that method for checkBox. because you are already checking for checkbox status inside button click.

Comment: @gvsharma if I remove `addListenerOnChk()`, the checkbox text does not display when save button clicked

Comment: `checkbox=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);` add this line in `onCreate()` method before you call onClick listener for *save* button.

Comment: check my answer regarding your question `why two separate onClick` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // if save button clicked

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
 if(checkbox.isChecked()) {
returnIntent.putExtra("outstation", checkbox.getText().toString());
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),checkbox.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
checkbox.setText("your text here");
      } else {
checkbox.setText("");
}
   }
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

The first method is correct..

The second method is not necessary. The checkBox.isChecked is everything you need to use.. you don't have to set the listener also for the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to this question

> "How can I put the check box inside save onClick instead of create two seperate OnClick ?"

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //your UI setup and findViewById stuff

        save.setOnClickListener(this);//implement - View.OnClickListener
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(this);//implement - View.OnClickListener
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);//prefer this one get check box status

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v.getId()==R.id.save_button){
            //save button action stuff
        } else if(v.getId()==R.id.check_box){
            //checkbox  button action stuff
            Log.i("TAG", " Check box status " + checkBox.isChecked());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        Log.i("TAG", " Check box status " + isChecked);
    }
```